# Using multiple columns dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

```
    A    B   C     D

1   X1   X2   Y1   Y2
2   0     0    2     2
3   0   0.1 2.15  2.15
```

I have 4 columns which I intend to use it in chart all at once , dynamically. Using cells within the range but not successful. Thanks in advance.

```
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(p).XValues = sh.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(3, 2))
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(p).Values = sh.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(3, 4))
```

Comment: what errors do you encounter?

Comment: `sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, 1), sh.Cells(3, 2))`   "Not successful" is not a useful description of the problem you're having with your code.

Comment: @Wils Mils: application defined or object defined error

Comment: @Tim Williams: application defined or object defined error

Comment: I am using line charts

Comment: Would help to show more of your code.  It looks like you're trying to add two series in one step though - you need to add them one by one

Comment: @Tim , I know to add them one at a time but I need to add them all at once this time.

Comment: It's not clear why you can't add the series individually. Why not?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to add two series in one step though - you need to add them one by one:

```vb
Dim rngX As Range, rngY As Range, n as long

Set rngX = sh.Range("A2:A3")
Set rngY = sh.Range("C2:C3")

For n = 1 to 2
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = rngX.offset(0, n-1)
        .Values = rngY.offset(0, n-1)
    End With
next n
```

Comment: I am connecting two co-ordinates to make multiple lines connecting (x1,y1,) and (x2,y2) =(0,2),(0,2)